# Flutter Failed assertion: line 1890 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedWidth':

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm working with `sqflite` database, and I want to show the sum of all scores stored in my DB.

I have a screen where I show a banner inside widget Stack, and I need to show the sum just right there.

But I get this error `Failed assertion:`

[image]

Here is an example image, which is what I need to show the sum in `Cumulative Score`:

[image: ![enter image description here]

this is how I call my database List to show on screen, a Positioned widget inside a Stack

```dart
  Positioned(
    right: 40,
    child: Expanded(

      //calling database

      child: FutureBuilder<List<scoregamilibre>>(                        
        future: _scoregamilibreRC,
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<List<scoregamilibre>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
              ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          } else {
            var items = snapshot.data ?? <scoregamilibre>[];

            print(items);

            return Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 1.0,
                vertical: 1.0,
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              ),
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder:
                    (BuildContext context, int index) {

                  //this are the scores parsed to int, to make the sum

                  int Ipos0 = int.parse(items[0].score);
                  int Ipos1 = int.parse(items[1].score);
                  int Ipos2 = int.parse(items[2].score);
                  int Ipos3 = int.parse(items[3].score);
                  int Ipos4 = int.parse(items[4].score);
                  int Ipos5 = int.parse(items[5].score);
                  int Ipos6 = int.parse(items[6].score);
                  int Ipos7 = int.parse(items[7].score);
                  int Ipos8 = int.parse(items[8].score);
                  int Ipos9 = int.parse(items[9].score);

                  int sumatoria = Ipos0 +
                      Ipos1 +
                      Ipos2 +
                      Ipos3 +
                      Ipos4 +
                      Ipos5 +
                      Ipos6 +
                      Ipos7 +
                      Ipos8 +
                      Ipos9;

                  //here is where i try to show in Text widget

                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: 7),
                        const Text(
                          "Sum Score",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontFamily: 'ZCOOL',
                              fontSize: 11),
                        ),
                        Text( 

                          //here is where it would be shown
                          sumatoria.toString(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: 'ZCOOL',
                            fontSize: 22,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  )
```

but before I go to that screen, that error appears:

```
Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1890 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedWidth': is not true.)
```

How can I resolve this error? maybe calling the database in another way? or do the sum inside dbHelper.dart and deliver the sum variable of the scores through a method?

Comment: Did you try to wrap your ListView inside an Expanded

Comment: Yes, but it still showing. I tried wrap inside Expanded and SizedBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `ListView` is only limited vertically by the `shrinkWrap` property. But horizontally, there is no limit on the left of the `Positioned`. To fix it do the following:

1. Remove the `Expanded` widget inside `Positioned`. This is because [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widgets *make a child of a **Row**, **Column**, or **Flex** expand to fill the available space along the main axis* -- but only in a **Row**, **Column**, or **Flex**. Mixing `Positioned` and `Expanded` is not OK.
2. Set the width of the `Container` to something like 100.0 (or set the `Positioned.left`). This will set the horizontal limits for the `ListView`.

The code is going to be like this:

```dart
Positioned(
  right: 40,
  child: FutureBuilder<List<scoregamilibre>>(
    future: _scoregamilibreRC,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      } else {
        var items = snapshot.data ?? <scoregamilibre>[];

        print(items);

        return Container(
          width: 100,                                      // <- Here
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 1.0,
            vertical: 1.0,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amber,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          ),
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              //this are the scores parsed to int, to make the sum

              int Ipos0 = int.parse(items[0].score);
              int Ipos1 = int.parse(items[1].score);
              int Ipos2 = int.parse(items[2].score);
              int Ipos3 = int.parse(items[3].score);
              int Ipos4 = int.parse(items[4].score);
              int Ipos5 = int.parse(items[5].score);
              int Ipos6 = int.parse(items[6].score);
              int Ipos7 = int.parse(items[7].score);
              int Ipos8 = int.parse(items[8].score);
              int Ipos9 = int.parse(items[9].score);

              int sumatoria = Ipos0 +
                  Ipos1 +
                  Ipos2 +
                  Ipos3 +
                  Ipos4 +
                  Ipos5 +
                  Ipos6 +
                  Ipos7 +
                  Ipos8 +
                  Ipos9;

              //here is where i try to show in Text widget

              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 7),
                    const Text(
                      "Sum Score",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontFamily: 'ZCOOL',
                          fontSize: 11),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      //here is where it would be shown
                      sumatoria.toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontFamily: 'ZCOOL',
                        fontSize: 22,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
)
```